# What should host information be for Nigerian tourist visas when staying at hotels?

Tags: visas, paperwork, applications, nigeria

When applying for an F5A tourist visa on the website of the Nigerian government, there are several required fields for information about the "host" in the country, such as their place of residence or their passport number.

Since, as far as I am aware, it is possible to travel to Nigeria for tourism and stay at a hotel without having a specific host in Nigeria, how should one fill out these fields for a tourist visa in such cases?

Comment: Are these fields mandatory for applicants staying in a hotel(s) for the entire trip?

Comment: @Traveller - Some are mandatory in programming terms. I do not know whether they are legally mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

To apply for a tourist visa, a confirmed hotel reservation is required if the applicant is not staying with a Host. Source: for example, [Embassy of Nigeria, Washington DC](https://nigeriaembassyusa.org/visas/) and [VisaHQ](https://www.visahq.co.uk/nigeria/)

It seems logical therefore that details of the applicant’s accommodation during the trip, such as name and address of the hotel, should be entered in these fields. In such cases, depending on how the online application system has been designed, I’d expect completion of irrelevant fields, eg the passport number, to either not be required or optional.